# База данных SQLite Django. Как в одной view сделать запись в базу данных для двух разных классов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть класс `Sklad`, он хранит информацию о материалах. Одно из полей - количество квадратных метров. Есть класс `Order` - информация о заказе. Во `view`, где создается заказ нужно, чтобы количество квадратных метров, которые есть в заказе отнялись из количества метров, которые были в складе и в базу данных записалось новое количество метров. То есть после создания заказа в складе количество материала должно уменьшиться на то количество, которое было в заказе.

**models.py**

```
class Sklad(models.Model):
    '''Склад материалов'''
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор материала', null=True)
    material = models.CharField('название', max_length=200)
    amount = models.IntegerField('количество', default='0')

class Order(models.Model):
    '''Заказ'''
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор заказа', null=True)
    material_order = models.ForeignKey(Sklad, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='материал', blank=True, null=True)
    area = models.IntegerField('площадь', default='0')
```

**views.py**

```
class OrderCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CustomSuccessMessageMixin, CreateView, ListView):
    model = Order
    template_name = 'orders.html'
    form_class = OrderForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('orders')
    success_msg = 'Заказ сохранён'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['list_orders'] = Order.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.author = self.request.user
        calkulation_order(self) # калькуляция заказа настраивается в отдельном файле
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```